# Binding collection to ContextMenu submenu

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having trouble doing something that seemed really easy but which is not actually.

I have a ListView in which i binded an ObservableCollection, and i want a ContextMenu to appear when i rightclick an element of that ListView.

In that ContextMenu, i want a MenuItem that says "Add to Playlist" and inside it, the list of all of my playlists.

So i did this, which looks right to me:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ListBoxSelectedFolder" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder.PlayableElements}">
      <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
          <MenuItem Header="Add to" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Playlists}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem Header="Remove from All" />
        </ContextMenu>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
      </ListView.Resources>
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The thing is that the only thing i get in my submenu is the name of the item i clicked on: somehow, it's binding with the collection of the ListView, SelectedFolder.PlayableElements, because both SelectedFolder.PlayableElements and Playlists have a Name property.

So there is some sort of conflict between the two bindings, and i don't know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: `<MenuItem Header="Add to" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Playlists}"><MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/></MenuItem>` - this means you set both `ItemsSource` and add item to `Items` of the parent MenuItem, which should throw some exception at runtime.

Comment: it does not throw exception for you to see because the `Binding` is silently  failed. `ContextMenu` is detached from visual tree so you need somehow to set the Binding source explicitly.

Comment: @KingKing How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: it is unclear where your `Playlists` comes from? such as from the `ListView`'s DataContext or some explicit sub-viewmodel?

Comment: @KingKing Actually it's an attribute of my MainWindow class

Comment: if you mean it's a custom attribute (inheriting from `System.Attribute`), then I don't think it's possible to pull attribute value (or its properties) right in XAML.

Comment: Not at all, it's just a property ! It has been declared like that: 
`public ObservableCollection<Playlist> Playlists {get;set;}`

Comment: The problem is that `Playlists` and  `SelectedFolder.PlayableElements` are both observable collections and they both have a Name property. So they are in conflict.

Comment: Check out the code in my answer, it should work for you now, if not please let me know what's wrong in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` is detached from the visual tree so Binding inside its scope with `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` is not possible in a normal way. You need some proxy technique to bridge the cutting. Here we have the `Freezable` element which can inherit data context as well as allow binding to walkup the visual tree even in this situation easily. For convenience we should use the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` because its Value can accept all kinds of object. If you care about the name, then you can define your own custom Freezable object.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ListBoxSelectedFolder" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder.PlayableElements}">
  <ListView.Resources>
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding Playlists, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="Add to" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
         <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Header="Remove from All" />
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.Resources>
  <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

**Edit** - this is to help you understand how you can mix the info from both Playlists and SelectedFolder:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ListBoxSelectedFolder" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder.PlayableElements}">
  <ListView.Resources>
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
      <MenuItem Header="Add to" ItemsSource="{Binding Playlists}">
         <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>                     
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>        
             </DataTemplate>
         </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem Header="Playable elements" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFolder.PlayableElements}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Remove from All" />
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.Resources>
  <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

As you can see the added menu item (right above the `Remove from all`) has its `ItemsSource` set to `SelectedFolder.PlayableElements`. The `ContextMenu` now has its `DataContext` set to the `Window` instance via `proxy`. So all the Bindings used inside its scope without explicit `Source` and  `RelativeSource` and `ElementName` set will get a resolved source of the DataContext (your window).

Comment: It works ! I didn't get why it didn't in the first place, why does it have to be so complicated when it sounds so logic ? 
Anyway thanks. Do you have some ressources to learn more about wpf, c# and .net ? It's really confused in my head.

Comment: Also, what if i wanted to mix properties from `SelectedFolder.PlayableElements` and `Playlists` in my `MenuItem` ?

Comment: @Devz yes I think it should not be so complicated, WPF itself has some problems that many don't like at all (and in fact it can totally be improved but somehow they don't). What I wrote here is from experience with the ContextMenu (and some others) so you should of course experience much to understand more about WPF. I suggest you to read the ***WPF Unleashed*** - it's a valuable book for beginner, just walk through its examples and guide. Of course it's not enough so it requires time to experience more, WPF has a steep learning curve.

Comment: For your additional question, I don't really get how you want to mix them, some example would be fine.

Comment: Let's say for exemple that i want in my submenu, in addition of the elements from `Playlists`, i also want the elements from `SelectedFolder.SomeObservableCollection`. How should i do that ?

Comment: @Devz Where is `SelectedFolder.SomeObservableCollection` from? is it also from your `MainWindow`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92026/discussion-between-devz-and-king-king).

Answer (score 0):

With code you showed you just bound another menu item to the name property. I guess what you are looking for is an **ItemTemplate** property of **MenuItem**. This way you can define what data should be shown for each child of this menu item.
Check the markup below:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ListBoxSelectedFolder" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder.PlayableElements}">
          <ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
              <MenuItem Header="Add to" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Playlists}">
                 <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem Header="Remove from All" />
            </ContextMenu>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
             <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
          </ListView.Resources>
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: What the difference between Binding Path and simple Binding ? I'm new to .NET specificities :(

Comment: Hm, will check it a bit later. There is no difference between "binding" and "binding path" I just think it's a bit more descriptive with "path"