# How to bind visibility of a control with context menu item IsChecked property?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls, contextmenu

(On clicking the menu item , the visibility of the textblock mentioned below should be changed, How can i achieve this using data binding)

```
            **<MenuItem Header="Lat/Long Info" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>**

     </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="MENU" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
        </Button.LayoutTransform>

        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource conmenu}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </Button.Style>

    </Button>
    **<TextBlock Text="Change my Visibility" Margin="50"></TextBlock>**
</Grid>
```

Please anyone help me with this issue , I am unable to find any solution

Comment: This post on proxy elements may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041089/binding-collection-to-contextmenu-submenu